# How can I use right and left square bracket for manifest.json?

Tags: javascript, html, json, minecraft

I try to create a manifest with JavaScript but minecraft can‘t read the right and left square bracket from JavaScript. What can I do so that minecraft is able to read the right and left square bracket?

```js
function create() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
  var x2 = '{\n"header" : {\n"version" : [\n0,\n0,\n1\n],\n"description" : "' + x[1].value + '",\n"name" : "' + x[0].value + '",\n"uuid" : "' + x[2].value + '"\n},\n"modules" : [\n{\n"version" : [\n0,\n0,\n1\n],\n"description" : "",\n"type" : "resources",\n"uuid" : "' + x[3].value + '"\n}\n],\n"format_version" : 1\n}';
  console.log(x2);
}
```

```html
Name: <input><br>
Discription: <input><br>
UUID: <input><br>
UUID2: <input><br>
<button onclick="create()">Create</button>
```

(Later I zip the variable x2 to a json-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of building a json-link string, you most likley want to use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) here.

```js
function create() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
  var output = {
    header: {
      version: [0, 0, 1],
      description: x[1].value,
      name: x[0].value,
      uuid: x[2].value,
    },
    modules: [
      {
        version: [0, 0, 1],
        description: '',
        type: 'resources',
        uuid: x[3].value,
      },
    ],
    format_version: 1,
  };
  console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 2));
}
```

```html
Name: <input><br>
Discription: <input><br>
UUID: <input><br>
UUID2: <input><br>
<button onclick="create()">Create</button>
```